# Calling a WEB API service from WCF service throws System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Am facing a weird issue ... we have multiple services application (separate VS solution altogether) and they communicate with other.

WCF service application consumes the WEB API service. All this services been deployed locally in IIS.

While testing I found that, WCF service app failing with below error

> Error occurred while getting response System.Net.WebException: The
>   underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
>   send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by
>   the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

The same works fine for my other team mates (with exact same application settings and IIS settings) in their local environment but for my case it's failing.

Did searched over internet and tried few of them but no luck (few suggested Firewall issue, which can't be since it's in local machine and moreover Firewall service is disabled).

I did put a break point by attaching the `w3wp` worker process and tried to debug and found that the call to WEB API service is not happening at all; means my break point to WEB API projects `Application_start()` doesn't hits at all.

Also yes (as asked by @Developer in comment) another strange stuff is that I can hit the WEB API from Browser or LinqPad and it works like a charm. Problem comes only when calling through WCF application code.

Any idea how can I solve this mess. Please suggests.

Comment: Are you able to hit your web api service via browser/fiddler? Is this issue happening only when hitting the service via code?

Comment: Any luck in the event viewer logs?

Comment: @Developer, nope .. nothing there. tried all that ... event viewer log, WCF tracing/message logging but no clue whatsoever.

Comment: may be fiddler might give some more info (my stupid doubt, I assume you have verified the service url being called from your wcf). Just to make sure this is environmental issue (not specific to that particular project), could you just create a simple app and try hitting the api from that app?

Comment: @Developer, LOL ... great minds thinks alike :)